# Microphone and Technique Suggestions for Recording Audiences?

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, audio, recording, microphone-positioning

I want to record an audience (people sounds), in rooms about 50 to 100 people. My main mic (Speaker) has 1.m distance from the audience mic, and I want to install the audience mic in 1.5m Height.

I want to buy the best audience mic and not very professional. I select this models:

1-[BeyerDynamic TG i53C Stereo Set](http://europe.beyerdynamic.com/shop/tg-i53c-stereo-set.html)

2-[AKG p170](http://www.akg.com/pro/p/p170)

my question is which is the best model for recording peoples sounds with best quality? is there any idea? these models is good? any points?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested the Beyerdynamic mic (and still haven't run into anyone using Beyerdynamic mics here in Norway), but the P170 sounds okay for most applications I've used it for (mostly as overheads for various instruments)

As Dalv writes, using multiple mics in multiple locations are the best option. You should also attempt to get some distance from the audience; if you don't, you risk having the audience recording dominated by a few very loud people rather than the crowd.

Answer (score 0):

For recording [wallas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walla) it's best to have either a multiple mic setup and to record from different spots.

Having some good quality recorded sounds that you could mix with mocap session or library samples is essential and using these techniques a wide array of crowd sounds can be achieved.

Comment: So we should have lots of mic for different locations. but which of these two mics is so better?

Comment: this is not answer my question